# Is it possible to have a loot table for a block tag in Minecraft 1.16.3?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands, minecraft-data-packs

I have a block tag and I wanted to know if I could make a loot table for the block tag.  If you don't know what a block tag is, a block tag is basically a group of blocks.  Could I make a loot table for a block tag so I don't have to rename the loot table for each block in the tag.  The block tag contains all blocks in the game.  Does anyone know if I could make a loot table for all of the blocks in the tag all at once?  Please ask questions.  I am in 1.16.3 java edition.